# External scripts like Slick.js, Typewriter.js not working when using barba.js v2 with wordpress custom theme. How to solve them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress-theming, slick.js, barbajs

For almost two weeks, I have been searching online, on GitHub, her in stack overflow for the right solution for my problems mentioned below, I am literally obsessed with barba but unfortunately I cant get it work for me.

I am sorry it is a long post. I hope someone here will be able to help me.

I am using barba.js v2 with WordPress (Not using elementor, I have created a custom theme created from scratch). I have set up functions.php to enqueue global styles & scripts on all pages and page-specific scripts and styles on respective pages.

## **Here is my Sample Directory:**

**Site Pages:**

- Home - front-page.php
- News/Blog - home.php
- About - page-templates/page_about.php
- Single News - single-post.php
- Team - page-templates/page_team.php
- Header
- Footer
- functions.php
- All css & js are in assets/css & assets/js folder

## **Javascript’s/libraries I’m using:**

**Global Scripts and styles:**

- styles.css
- bootstrap.min.css
- Jquery 3.6.0 (defer)
- main.js (defer) (used for header nav menu)
- Barba-core v2 (defer) (from cdn.jsdelivr)
- gsap.min (defer) (cdn)
- page-transition.js (defer) (for barba.init())

**The following are the page-specific Global Scripts and CSS**

- Slick.js (Should be loaded only in home, about & news page)
- Bootstrap.js (Should be loaded only in team page)
- Typewritter.js (Should be loaded only in home page)

**Individual Page-specific styles and scripts:**

- Home.css & home.js (contains slick and typewritter config)
- about.css & about.js (contains slick config)
- team.css
- news.css & news.js (contains multiple slick config)
- Single-post.css

## **Issues:**

- Not able to apply slick and typewriter js on required pages
- When I load the website home page and then go to the about page it works. And If I reload the about page, it is also working. After reloading the about page and when I go back to the home page and then if I come back to the about page the slick slider breaks.
- On the home page, the typewriter js is initially loaded, but when I come back from any other page to the home page it won’t work.

**Here is my page-transition.js**

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {

    barba.init({
        debug: true,
        logLevel: 'debug',
        sync: false
    });

    barba.hooks.afterLeave(data => {
        var nextPageStyle = data.next.namespace;
        let nextPagescript =  data.next.container.querySelector("#primary").getAttribute("class").trim().split(" ");
        var newScriptUrl = "http://localhost/website/wp-content/themes/mytheme/assets/js/" + nextPageStyle + ".js";

        // I have added 'css' or 'js' classes via php function to div#primary in my header.php depending on the page-specific.css and page-specific.js enqueued in the page
        if (nextPagescript.includes("js")) {

            // If div#primary has 'js' class
            $.getScript( newScriptUrl, function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
                // For ex: in home.js, I have added var Scripts { init: function () }
                Scripts.init();
                alert("Scripts initiated");
            });
        }

        // I have added 'slick', 'bootstrap', 'typewritter' classes via php function to div#main in my header.php depending on which page has slick or bootstrap or typewritter js
        let currentClassArray = data.current.container.querySelector("#main").getAttribute("class").trim().split(" ");
        let nextPageClassArray = data.next.container.querySelector("#main").getAttribute("class").trim().split(" ");


        // If the current page has Slick and next page doesn't, remove slick
        if (currentClassArray.includes("slick") && !(nextPageClassArray.includes("slick"))) {
               $('link[rel=stylesheet][id~="slick-css"]').remove();
               $('script[id~="slick-js"]').remove();
        } else if (!(currentClassArray.includes("slick")) && nextPageClassArray.includes("slick")) {
               // If the current page doesn't have Slick and next page does have slick, include them
               $("head").append(
                   '<link rel="stylesheet" id="slick-css" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/website/wp-content/themes/mytheme/assets/slick/slick/slick.css" />'
               );
               $.getScript( "http://localhost/website/wp-content/themes/mytheme/assets/slick/slick/slick.min.js", function( ) {
                   // Scripts.init();
               });
        } else if ((currentClassArray && nextPageClassArray).includes("slick")) {
                // If both pages have slick, do nothing
        } else if (!(currentClassArray && nextPageClassArray).includes("slick")) {
                //  If both pages do not have slick, do nothing
        }

        // If it is home page, include typewritter, if it is not already included
        if (nextPageStyle == "home") {
            if (document.querySelector('script[id="typewritter-js"][src="http://localhost/website/wp-content/themes/mytheme/assets/typewritter/typewritter.js"]')) {
                alert("True");
            } else {
                alert("False");
                $.getScript( "http://localhost/website/wp-content/themes/mytheme/assets/typewritter/typewritter.js", function( ) {
                     alert("Script loaded");
                });
            }
        } else { }
    });


    // Before Enter
    barba.hooks.beforeEnter(data => {
        var nextPageStyle = data.next.namespace;
        
        var newStyleUrl = "http://localhost/website/wp-content/themes/mytheme/assets/css/" + nextPageStyle + ".css";
        var newScriptUrl = "http://localhost/website/wp-content/themes/mytheme/assets/js/" + nextPageStyle + ".js";

        let nextpagehasCss = data.next.container.querySelector("#primary").getAttribute("class").trim().split(" ");

        if (nextpagehasCss.includes("css")) {
            $("head").append(
                '<link rel="stylesheet" id="' + nextPageStyle + '-css" type="text/css" href="' + newStyleUrl + '" />'
            );
        }
    });


    // Enter
    barba.hooks.enter(data => {

        // Update body class
        let parser = new DOMParser();
        let htmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(
            data.next.html.replace(
                /(<\/?)body( .+?)?>/gi,
                "$1notbody$2>",
                data.next.html
            ),
            "text/html"
        );
        let bodyClasses = htmlDoc.querySelector("notbody").getAttribute("class");
        $("body").attr("class", bodyClasses);


        // Remove Previous Page Style and Js
        let previousPagehasCss = data.current.container.querySelector("#primary").getAttribute("class").trim().split(" ");
        let nextPagehasJs = data.next.container.querySelector("#primary").getAttribute("class").trim().split(" ");
        var currentPageStyle = data.current.namespace;

        if (previousPagehasCss.includes("css")) {
            $('link[rel=stylesheet][id~="' + currentPageStyle + '-css"]').remove();
        }
        
        if (previousPagehasCss.includes("js")) {
            $('script[id~="' + currentPageStyle + '-js"]').remove();
        }
    });

   
});
```

**Here is my header.php**

```
<?php

/**
 * The header.
 * 
 * This is the template that displays all of the <head> section and everything up until main.
 * 
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage website
 * @since My Theme 1.0
 */
?>

<!doctype html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>

<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="profile" href="https://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?> data-barba="wrapper">
<?php
    if (is_front_page()) {
        $get_url_name = "home";
    } elseif (is_home()) {
        $get_url_name = "news";
    } elseif (is_singular('post')) {
        $get_url_name = "single-post";
    } else {
        $get_url_name = basename(get_permalink());
    }
?>
    <div id="page" class="site">
        // Nav Menu
        <?php get_template_part('template-parts/header/site-header'); ?>

        <div class="loader"></div>

        <div id="content" class="site-content " data-barba="container" data-barba-namespace="<?php echo $get_url_name; ?>">
            // function stylescript() adds 'css' or 'js' classes if the current page has page-specific css or js like home.css or home.js
            <div id="primary" class="content-area <?php stylescript(); ?>">
                // function main_class() adds 'slick', 'bootstrap', or 'typewritter' classes if the current page requires any of these global page-specific scripts
                <div id="main" class="site-main <?php main_class(); ?>" role="main">
```

**Here is my home.js**

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  Scripts.init();
});

// Slick Carousal settings
var Scripts = {
  init: function () {
     const nextArrow = `<button class='nextArrow btn'><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="40" height="40" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-arrow-right-short" viewBox="0 0 16 16"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M4 8a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h5.793L8.146 5.354a.5.5 0 1 1 .708-.708l3 3a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-3 3a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708L10.293 8.5H4.5A.5.5 0 0 1 4 8z"/></svg> </button>`;

    const prevArrow = `<button class='prevArrow btn'><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="40" height="40" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-arrow-left-short" viewBox="0 0 16 16"> <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M12 8a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5H5.707l2.147 2.146a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708l-3-3a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708l3-3a.5.5 0 1 1 .708.708L5.707 7.5H11.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5z"/></svg></button>`;

    const carousel_settings = {
      dots: false,
      infinite: false,
      arrows: true,
      prevArrow,
      nextArrow,
      speed: 300,
      slidesToShow: 2.5,
      slidesToScroll: 1,

      responsive: [
        {
          breakpoint: 992,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 1.5,
          },
        },
        {
          breakpoint: 769,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 1,
          },
        },
      ],
    };

    $(".testimonial-slider").slick(carousel_settings);
    $(".latest_video--carousel-container").slick({
      ...carousel_settings,
    });

    // TODO :- TYPEWRITER EFFECT
    const ele = document.getElementById("typewriter-effect");
    if (ele) {
      new Typewriter(ele, {
        strings: ["Hi", "Hello", "Houdy"],
        autoStart: true,
        loop: true,
      });
    }
  }
};
```

**Here is about.js**

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  Scripts.init();
});

var Scripts = {
  init: function () {
    const nextArrow = `<button class='nextArrow btn'><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="40" height="40" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-arrow-right-short" viewBox="0 0 16 16"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M4 8a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h5.793L8.146 5.354a.5.5 0 1 1 .708-.708l3 3a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-3 3a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708L10.293 8.5H4.5A.5.5 0 0 1 4 8z"/></svg> </button>`;

const prevArrow = `<button class='prevArrow btn'><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="40" height="40" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-arrow-left-short" viewBox="0 0 16 16"> <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M12 8a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5H5.707l2.147 2.146a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708l-3-3a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708l3-3a.5.5 0 1 1 .708.708L5.707 7.5H11.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5z"/>
</svg></button>`;

    $(".carousel-slider").slick({
      dots: false,
      infinite: false,
      arrows: true,
      nextArrow,
      prevArrow,
      speed: 300,
      slidesToShow: 2.5,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      responsive: [
        {
          breakpoint: 982,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 1.3,
          },
        },

        {
          breakpoint: 650,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 1,
          },
        },
      ],
    });
  },
};
```

**Here is the footer.php**

```
<?php

/**
 * Footer
 * 
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage website
 * @since My Theme 1.0
 */

?>
</div><!-- #main -->
</div><!-- #primary -->

</div><!-- #content -->

<footer>...</footer>

</div><!-- #page -->

<?php wp_footer(); ?>

</body>

</html>
```

**Following are the tutorials I followed:**

- https://ooohboi.space/barba/barba-main-page
- https://www.fjobeir.com/implement-barba-v2-with-wordpress/
- https://www.fjobeir.com/implement-barba-js-with-wordpress/
- https://thisisadvantage.com/page-transitions-using-barba-js-wordpress-elementor/

I was able to solve many of the issues I had by referring to the above tutorials, but for some I am not able to make it work.

It would be a great help if anybody helps me understand what I am doing wrong here and tell me how to solve this.
Thank you

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking for a good solution to this, I had a similar problem with web components (custom HTML elements) not initializing when their script tags were in the barba-container.

I came up with this:

```
barba.init({
    ...whatever settings you have,
    transitions:[{
       name: : "your-transition-name",
       
       beforeEnter(data) {
           const nextEl = data.next.container;
           if (nextEl) { //Just a little check to make sure we don't run this on an error
               // Find all scripts in the next container
               const nextScripts = nextEl.querySelectorAll('script');
    
               //Iterate over incoming script tags
               nextScripts.forEach(nextScript => {
                  const src = nextScript.src;
                  //Duplicate check - no need to re-execute scripts that are already loaded.
                  if (document.head.querySelector('script[src="' + src + '"]') == undefined) {

                    //Have to create a new script element in order for the browser to execute the code
                    const newScript = document.createElement('script');
                    newScript.src = src;
                    newScript.async = true; 
                    document.head.append(newScript);

                    nextScript.remove(); // Cleaning up the script in the container;
                  }
           }
       },
       (...whatever other transition functions you need, like after(), once(), etc.)



});
```

I'm pretty sure this solves the primary problem of the script not being executed, by **creating a new script tag in the header** for each script tag being loaded in the body. (It seems as if the body HTML is being loaded in such a way that re-executing scripts doesn't happen, which is normal for AJAX replacement).